# Ctrl-C does not work with pppd non-detached session

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, tmux, ppp

I have a Mini2440 ARM Board, and I have put a base Debian 6.0 system on it using `multistrap`.

I have used `tmux` to run several processes in defferent windows from `/etc/rc.local`. I connect to the board using its serial port and an inittab entry to run `getty` on that port. I use `picocom` as serial communicator.

When root logs in, `~/.bashrc` attaches him to the already running tmux server, and processes can be easily monitored. the actual command is `exec tmux attach-session -t "main"`. tmux runs with default config.

Everything works, except one of the processes (a shell script around `pppd`) does not receive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> from terminal, while other processes do. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> works. **also  `kill -INT <pppd_pid>` works, but `kill -INT <shellscript_pid>` does not.**

I really need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to work. What is wrong with this setup?

Edit:
here is the output of `stty -a` in the shell script, right before `pppd`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 23; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

since it's just `pppd` process that has this issue, I think it has something to do with it or its configuration, but when I run `pppd` outside of tmux, Ctrl-C works. `pppd` runs with `nodetach` option, so it stays in terminal foreground.

I also tested it on my dev machine (Debian 6.0 on amd64) with the same results.

Comment: Does `stty -a` show `intr = ^C`? If not, what is the `intr` setting? (Note: `stty -a | grep intr` won't work, since it makes `stty` write to a pipe rather than to your tty.) Does Ctrl-V Ctrl-C echo `^C`? If not, what does it echo?

Comment: @KeithThompson Ctrl-V prints a `^` and Ctrl-C adds a `C` to it.

Comment: This seems too obvious, but is there a `trap` command in the shell script?

Comment: @KeithThompson no there isnt. `trap` returns nothing. I guess it has something to do with changes that tmux makes to terminal behaviour and assumptions that pppd makes about terminal.

Comment: can anyone confirm this on their system? perhaps I could report this as a bug to either tmux or ppp developers.

Comment: same issue here under OSX 10.8.2 (update from this week) - tmux 1.7 - in little shell apps like "top" ctrl+C is just completely ignored - nothing happens.

Comment: typing "stty sane" fixes it but i dont know if thats permanent.

Comment: `pppd` has no say in what its underlying shell decides to do with a direct SIGINT. Try writing a tiny shell script that invokes /bin/sleep 600 and send the shell process a SIGINT, you'll see the exact same thing.

Comment: I don't know tmux well enough but I suspect pppd detects that it doesn't have a terminal despite running under tmux and then ignores INT signals.  a trace of pppd while it is started, as well as when tmux is "Detatched" the first time, will probably be telling.

Comment: Ctrl-z, kill %%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a bug in the particular version of `pppd` that was being used in the distro. I checked and previous and later versions of `pppd` do not have this problem. Also the problem is not specific to this arch and platform or `tmux`. If `pppd` is being run inside a shell script, It does not handle Ctrl-C, while outside shell, it has no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever thought about givin GNU screen a try? To be very honest i havent much experience with tmux, but screen always did the job nicely.